# Modifying class properties in a method

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, inner-classes

I'm studying OOP and how frameworks like jQuery works. If i create class with methods which change class properties it's changes it for all variable calls:

```
class test{

        constructor(selector) {
            this.el = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
            return this;
        }

        find(selector) {
            this.el = this.el[0].querySelectorAll(selector); //well...
            return this;
        }

}

function x(selector){ return new test(selector); }

var p = x('#parent'); //returns #parent
var c = p.find('#child') //returns #child
console.log(p); //returns #child too!
```

But if i use jQuery it works like what i need:

```
var p = $('#parent'); //returns #parent
var c = p.find('#child') //returns #child
console.log(p); //returns #parent
```

I understand what "find" method replaces class's properties, and variable "p" is just like a shortcut to class instance. But how to make it work like it works in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way jQuery does it is that it doesn't give you *the same* element as before but a *new one*. If we use the same technique with your code, it will look a bit like this:

```
class test{

        constructor(selector) {
            this.el = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
            return this;
        }

        find(selector) {
            return new test(selector); //return a new instance
        }

}

function x(selector){ return new test(selector); }

var p = x('#parent'); //will return #parent
var c = p.find('#child') //will return #child - this is a separate instance
console.log(p); //will still return #parent because it's not modified by .find()
```

This example might be a bit oversiplified but the general idea remains - do not modify the state of the main object, if you don't want it to change. If you do need to act on the new state but still keep the old one, then it's easier to just have two objects.